# Can I write IO bound RSpec tests more efficiently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fedora-commons

I am working on a project that focuses on archiving documents.  As part of this process we use the [Fedora Repository Architecture](https://duraspace.org/fedora/).  While Fedora is a great backend for a repository, writing to Fedora is a slow process and it is causing the run time of our test suite to soar.

When faced with a group of IO bound tests, is there a way to allow other tests to run while waiting for the slow ones to complete in RSpec?

Answer (score 0):

One strategy could be to tag you IO bound specs and run the separately.
So, you could tag your tests as follows:

```rb
describe "MyClass", :io_bound do
  it "is IO intensive" do
    # your tests
  end
end

describe "MyOtherClass" do
  it "is not IO intensive" do
    # your tests
  end
end
```

Then you run them separately with:

```
rspec . --tag=io_bound # runs all specs tagged as io bound
```

```
rspec . --tag=~io_bound # runs all specs NOT tagged as io bound (all your other tests)
```